# Concentration inequality for of sum of iid Geometric random variables taken to some power

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, conditional-probability, concentration-of-measure

I am interested in techniques for showing the concentration of sum of $n$ iid geometric random variables $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$, say with success probability $p = 1/2$, taken to some power $d$. Let $S_n^{(d)} = X_1^d + \cdots + X_n^d$ be the sum of the random variables and let $\mu_d = \mathbb{E}(S_n^{(d)})$. I would like to show something of the form

$$P\left\lbrace S_n^{(d)} > (1 + \delta) \mu_d \right\rbrace \leq C\exp\left(-f(\delta) n^{\alpha}\right)$$

for some positive constant $C$, some $\delta \geq 0$, and some $0 < \alpha \leq 1$ that may be a function of $d$. For the case that $d = 1$, one is able to use a standard Chernoff type approach to obtain that

$$P\left\lbrace S_n^{(1)} > (1 + \delta) \mu_1 \right\rbrace \leq \exp\left(-g(\delta) n\right)$$

using the fact that $\mu_1 = 2n$ and letting $g(\delta) = (1 + 2\delta) \log\left(1 + 2 \delta\right) - 2 (1 + \delta) \log\left(1 + \delta\right)$. However, it seems such an approach breaks down for $d > 1$ because finding an upper bound for $\mathbb{E}\left(\exp(s X_i^d)\right)$, where $s$ is some positive parameter, is not possible.

The idea I had instead is to break the probability into pieces by conditioning. Let $b$ be some positive real number to be set later. Let $B$ be the indicator r.v. that is 1 if and only if $\forall i: X_i \leq b$ and let $E_d$ be an indicator that is $1$ if and only if $S_n^{(d)} > (1 + \delta) \mu_d$. Then we can do

\begin{align}
P\left\lbrace E_d = 1 \right\rbrace &= P\left\lbrace E_d = 1 | B = 1\right\rbrace \underbrace{P\left\lbrace B = 1 \right\rbrace}_{\leq 1} + \underbrace{P\left\lbrace E_d = 1 | B = 0\right\rbrace}_{\leq 1} P\left\lbrace B = 0\right\rbrace \\
&\leq P\left\lbrace E_d = 1 | B = 1\right\rbrace + P\left\lbrace B = 0\right\rbrace
\end{align}

By union bound, we can find that

\begin{align}
P\left\lbrace B = 0 \right\rbrace &= P\left\lbrace \exists i: X_i > b\right\rbrace \\
&\leq \frac{n}{2^b} \\
&= \exp\left(-(b \ln(2) - \ln(n)\right)
\end{align}

Also, $P\left\lbrace E_d = 1 | B = 1\right\rbrace$ seems to be something we can reason about with Hoeffding's inequality (using generalized sum version [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality)) now since by the conditioning, the random variables in the sum are bounded. To help simplify this, I also worked out that $\frac{d! n}{2 \ln^{d+1}(2)} \leq \mu_d \leq \frac{d! n}{\ln^{d+1}(2)}$. With these ideas, we can find that

\begin{align}
P\left\lbrace E_d = 1 | B = 1\right\rbrace &= P\left\lbrace S_n^{(d)} > (1 + \delta) \mu_d | \forall i: X_i \leq b\right\rbrace \\
&\leq \exp\left(- \frac{\delta^2 \mu_d^2}{n b^{2d}}\right) \\
&\leq \exp\left(- \left(\frac{ \delta d!}{2 \ln^{d+1}(2)}\right)^2 \frac{n}{b^{2d}}\right)
\end{align}

If we combine the results, we obtain

\begin{align}
P\left\lbrace S_n^{(d)} > (1 + \delta) \mu_d \right\rbrace &\leq \exp\left(- \left(\frac{ \delta d!}{2 \ln^{d+1}(2)}\right)^2 \frac{n}{b^{2d}}\right) + \exp\left(-(b \ln(2) - \ln(n)\right) \\
&\leq 2 \exp\left(- \min \left \lbrace \left(\frac{ \delta d!}{2 \ln^{d+1}(2)}\right)^2 \frac{n}{b^{2d}}, b \ln(2) - \ln(n)\right \rbrace \right)
\end{align}

If one chooses $b = n^{1/(2d+1)}$, then for large enough $n$ we have

\begin{align}
P\left\lbrace S_n^{(d)} > (1 + \delta) \mu_d \right\rbrace &\leq 2 \exp\left(- n^{1/(2d+1)}\min \left \lbrace \left(\frac{ \delta d!}{2 \ln^{d+1}(2)}\right)^2, \ln(2)/2\right \rbrace \right)
\end{align}

which just about give us a result that fits what we want. However, this seems to be a bit weak, especially since setting $d = 1$ gives us an exponent for $n$ of $1/3$, which is noticeably worse than what was found by Chernoff.

Any recommendations or ideas on how one can obtain a stronger result for the $d > 1$ cases?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4086052/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/520626/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139548/755